# Concourse tries to pull docker image using wrong sha256 digest and fails

Tags: dockerfile, concourse, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running Concourse 3.10.0, which I installed with [the official helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse), on GKE. I am getting this error, which refers to the wrong sha256:

```
Pulling registry.hub.docker.com/linkyard/concourse-helm-release@sha256:c47e868ec58fcf81b3b0d597bd10a91fc1908da4c13561e7834584997d1fcb9d...
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.hub.docker.com/linkyard/concourse-helm-release, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

If I run `docker pull linkyard/concourse-helm-resource:2.8.2-3` locally, it works, but downloads a different sha256.

It looks to me like I have run into [issue 33 in concourse's docker-image-resource plugin](https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource/issues/33), but that was fixed 2 years ago.

I had a little look at [the Concourse Dockerfile](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) and the helm chart, but I couldn't figure out how docker-image-resource gets included into the Concourse deployment.

How can I upgrade docker-image-resource to see if that fixes this bug?

Comment: It is telling you `repository does not exist`. This smells of one of the DNS problems you can get with Concourse, which are often resolved by setting the garden dns server to something always reachable like 8.8.8.8. The fact that it works locally is misleading, I got bitten by the same. The name resolution happens inside Garden, in a different network namespace. Is your concourse installation able to download other resources ?

Comment: Yes, it is able to download from Google's own container repository, which is what I tried to use first.

Comment: So you are using `helm install councourse` command?

Comment: Yes, that's what I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually just a simple typo - `concourse-helm-release` instead of `concourse-helm-resource` - but the error messages were misleading.

For future reference, the docker-image-resource is baked into the Concourse docker image by BOSH, and the relevant version can be found in [this file](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/master/config/blobs.yml).